# Unable to pull text from elements within shadow-root using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a terrible time getting text from shadow-root. I found several docs and it looks right to me, except i always get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python\vttest.py", line 29, in 
print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('vt-ui-shell').shadowRoot.querySelector('url-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-main-generic-report').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-url-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('p')").text)
File "C:\Users\barberion.NATJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
return self.execute(command, {
File "C:\Users\barberion.NATJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\barberion.NATJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.93)

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities # necessary in headless mode, need this library to accept ssl

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

#from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()

capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True 

capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

opts = Options()

#opts.headless = True # comment this out to get out of headless

#opts.add_argument("--window-size=1400x1400")

opts.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")

opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

searchvt=input("Enter URL: ")

driver = Chrome(options=opts,desired_capabilities=capabilities,executable_path='C:/python/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url')

url='//*[@id="view-container"]/home-view'

time.sleep(.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(url).send_keys(searchvt)

time.sleep(.5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(url).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

time.sleep(3)

print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('vt-ui-shell').shadowRoot.querySelector('url-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-main-generic-report').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-url-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('p')").text)
```

my error must be somewhere in the print :( any help is most appreciated!

Edit:
To be more specific, I want to submit an URL or domain to virustotal, and then read the result text on top of page. If you use MSN.com the text I want is on top where it says "No security vendors flagged this URL as malicious"

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: this will submit a domain or url to virus total and then read back if its malicious or not. the text im looking for is nested inside shadow-root. im not able to locate it

Comment: An example of _searchvt_ for us to test?

Comment: anything will work, msn.com

Comment: What info do want to pull out? There are tons of texts

Comment: right on top where it says "No security vendors flagged this URL as malicious"

Comment: Can you update the main question with all these info in the comments?

Comment: all set thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My shadow DOMS were just out of order. once i modified print to:

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('url-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-url-card').shadowRoot.querySelector('vt-ui-generic-card').querySelector('p')").text)
```

everything functioned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you update to Selenium 4.0 and use a Chromium browser v96+ you can use the new `shadow_root` property in Python Selenium and avoid using JavaScript entirely.

This is a working example:

```
driver.get('http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html')

shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_host')
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#shadow_content')

assert shadow_content.text == 'some text'
```

Source: https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html

Comment: I cannot get this to work for the requested project :(

Comment: Are you using Selenium 4.1? What error do you get? Did you read the other solutions in the link?